# bootstrap 3 navbar active li background

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, navbar

I have a bootstrap navbar in [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mpsbhat/363voefy/1) and its dropdown is visible on hover the mouse as

```
 $('.navbar .dropdown').hover(function () {
        $(this).find('.dropdown-menu').first().stop(true, true).slideDown(300);
    }, function () {
        $(this).find('.dropdown-menu').first().stop(true, true).slideUp(180)
    });
```

But how to make the parent li background still active as when mouseover down to dropdown menu similar to one [without sliding](https://jsfiddle.net/mpsbhat/363voefy/2/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply add class `open` on-hover and remove it on mouse leave.
See below example,

```js
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('.navbar .dropdown').hover(function() {
        $(this).addClass('open');
      },
      function() {
        $(this).removeClass('open');
      });
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://getbootstrap.com/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://getbootstrap.com/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
    </div>

    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>

    </div>
    <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div>
  <!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>
```